# Contar rows affected utilizando un proceso almacenado SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

tengo un problema para poder contar las filas que afecta la ejecución de un proceso almacenado, el cual se ejecuta y recibe 6 parámetros. Al ejecutarse, me muestra como resultado de la ejecución la cantodad de filas afectadas, de hecho me muestra 2 valores de filas afectadas.

Necesitaría, poder tomar ese valor que devuelve la ejecución. No estaría seguro si @@ROWCOUNT me estaría contando lo que necesito haciendo agregandolo abajo del EXEC del proceso almacenado, porque me devuelve 0.

Existe alguna manera de poder obtener el valor de filas afectadas que me muestra luego de la ejecución del proceso almacenado?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos!

Comment: Hola como dices @@ROWCOUNT deberia de ayudarte en ese proceso, tal como lo puedes ver en este ejemplo 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=57082f9bf817eb84025ead8e25ae0210
Devuelve 4 que son las filas que se vieron afectadas

Comment: `@ROWCOUNT` tiene que ser la siguiente clausula después de cualquier sentencia de `select, update, delete, insert`, no puedes usarlo fuera del `store procedure`, y si te interesa sumar varios `@@rowcount` tienes que acumularlos en una variable y retornar la mismas desde el SP o como parámetro del tipo `output`. Lo ideal es que agregues el código de lo que estás intentando, por que lo que te comento es simplemente una hipótesis.